# Запрос в MS-Access с помощью Count

Tags: ms-access

Здравствуйте нужна помощь, через запрос нужно подсчитать сколько людей занимаются определенным видом спорта. Пробовал через count но почему-то БД считает что если один и тот же человек занимался одинаковым видом спорта два и больше раз то это разные люди а не один и тот же человек,
вот моя схема запроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот моя  таблица «Результат» по которой нужно найти сколько человек занимается определенным видом спорта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот мой запрос но почему-то под спортом с айди 2 занимаются 5 человек а должно 4 так как спортсмен под айди 1 занимается одним и тем же спортом но в разных командах, но БД считает что это абсолютно два разных человека:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой запрос надо написать чтобы показывало правильное количество людей которое занимается определенным спортом ?

Comment: Считать надо `COUNT(DISTINCT Спортсмен_id)`.

Comment: @Akina, SELECT Результат.Дисциплина_id, COUNT (DISTINCT Результат.Спортсмен_id)
FROM [Результат];  так должно быть ?

Comment: По-моему, быстрее попробовать, чем спрашивать...

Comment: @Akina  просто я так пробывал, но выдавало ошибку в DISTINCT

Comment: Если версия не принимает DISTINCT - делайте группировку по этому полю... и вообще текст запроса бы в вопрос добавить не помешало.

Comment: @Akina я делаю запрос через конструктор запросов в MS Access 2016

Comment: Сделал запрос в конструкторе - топни на нём правым батоном в поле таблиц и выбери "Режим SQL".